# How to add images in JTextPane?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtextpane

I want to give the user the facility to copy and paste ***Images***
in `JTextPane`. Please help me.

Comment: dude, What have you done for this until now?

Comment: I googled "image jtextpane", and the top 5 results all contained a solution with code on how to do this. So my suggestion is, try implementing one of those examples, and if you get stuck, post that specific question here and we can try to help you out

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson  Any links at SO you'd care to share? A Good SO link with an accepted answer would be ample grounds to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I am Sorry, I was not online for the past 3 hours and above. I will try it now. Thank you very Much!!!!

Comment: I googled and found one. It displays but I want the user to Copy the Image and paste it in the TextPane, like WordPad and MS Word.

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy way to add an image:

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane ();
pane.insertIcon ( new ImageIcon ( "/path/to/image.png" ) );
```

But there is no simple way to copy an image from the pane, since it cannot be selected and cannot be easily located in the pane document.

Comment: For my own uses I found that this works even better: `pane.insertComponent( new JLabel(myIcon) )`

Answer (score 4):

You need a StyledDocument, like resulting from HTML. Hence set the content type to "text/html". Then `<img src="file:...">` will link to an image on the file system.

Then you can provide drag-and-drop or paste from File or Image (the latter you have to save in your own files).